# Swift 3 embed button in page view controller

Tags: swift, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

i am trying to set up a pageviewcontroller that has embedded buttons ( those that dont move when the page view is swipped left or right but are constantly visable )

i have the standard viewcontroller, the pageviewcontroller, and another viewcontroller that has an imageview.  the problem is that regardless where i place the buttons they move off screen whith the swipe an reappear with the new image.

is there a way of embeding them so they dont move off each swipe?

ive even tried placing an embedded navigation controller on the first viewcontroller but with no success.

thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want them to move, you have to put them in the view controller that contains your UIPageViewController. So they will be only one instance of the button (not one for each pages).